# Local references in imported Terraform module

Tags: bitbucket, terraform

I have TF modules on bitbucket in the terraform-modules project.

In my main module (in the azure/main_module directory) on bitbucket I have:

```
azure
  |
  +- sub_module
     main.tf
main_module
     main.tf
```

In `main_module/main.tf` I have the following file structure:

```
azure
   |
   +-general
      |
      +-main.tf
```

```
module "my_sub_module" {
    source  = "../azure/sub_module/"
...
}
```

Now, in another project, in another module I have:

```
module "credit" {
    source = "git::bitbucket.org:myorg/terraform-modules.git//main_module"
...
}
```

I get the following error when running tf plan in the other project:

```
Error: Unreadable module directory
Unable to evaluate directory symlink: lstat
.terraform/modules/main_module/azure/azure: no such file or directory
```

Everything works when the local references are replaced with bitbucket references.
So it seems as though the main_module is imported, but then the local references in that project is are interpreted as local references in the importing project (the one with the general module) and then it can't find additional modules because it is searching in the wrong project?

Any ideas how this can be fixed, while still using local references in the imported project?

Comment: Your relative path is wrong. From the main module it's `../sub_module` to get to the sub_module directory. You might want to test running `cd ../sub_module` to see where the relative path goes or even using `readlink --canonicalize ../sub_module` or `find .. -name sub_module -type d` to see the path to it.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the comment and sorry, the directory structure was indicated incorrectly. I have fixed this.